# checking for a character in div.innerHtml resulting in undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript function which executes upon document
   ready function of a partial view in MVC ASP.NET application. I check
   for this div if it contains a character -"|" and if it does I replace
   it with a br-line break. My code works as expected on my local
   environment but when I publish my solution to the windows server on
   my intranet, I get undefined string.

so basically the line `if(DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML[i] == "|")` never comes out to be true on the server, The div does has the string which contains the character so I am baffled as to why this condition is   never true on the server.

Any ideas?

```
 var DIV_CHECK7 = document.getElementById("ErrorDisplayNoId");
            alert(DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML);


        var DIV_OUTPUT7 = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML.length; ++i) {
            if (DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML[i] == "|") {
                DIV_OUTPUT7 += "<br/>";
            }
            else {
                DIV_OUTPUT7 += DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML[i];

            }
        }

        DIV_CHECK7.innerHTML = DIV_OUTPUT7;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple call to [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) be easier here?

```
DIV7_CHECK7.innerHTML = DIV7_CHECK7.innerHTML.replace(/\|/g,'<br>')
```

Comment: It'd need to be a global replace wouldn't it? `.replace(/\|/g,'<br>')`